# Django Rest queryset inside APIview

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two serializers for two models but I want to combine those two serializers into one view

```
class ProductRequestView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def get(self, request):

        city_serializer = CityCompactSerializer
        models = ModelsNestedSerializer

        data = {'cities':{'city data'},
                'models': {'models data'}}

        return Response(data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

I think I have to pass queryset to both serializers to get the data. How can I do it inside this view. I am new to DRF. Help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class ProductRequestView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def get(self, request):

        data = {
            'cities': CategoryCompactSerializer(<CategoryModel>.objects.all(), many=True).data
            'models': ModelsNestedSerializer(<ModelsModel>.objects.all(), many=True).data
        }

        return Response(data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```